# Spark: Broadcasting a multimap

Tags: apache-spark

I have a fairly small lookup file that I need to broadcast for efficiency.

If the key value pairs are unique, then you can use the following code to distribute the file as a hashmap across worker nodes.

```
val index_file = sc.textFile("reference.txt").map { line => ( (line.split("\t"))(1), (line.split("\t"))(0)) }
val index_map = index_file.collectAsMap()
sc.broadcast(index_map)
```

Unfortunately, the file has several entries for a given key. Is there any way to distribute this multimap variable? Reading the documentation, looks like collectAsMap does not support a multimap.

```
val mmap = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String, collection.mutable.Set[Int]]() with collection.mutable.MultiMap[String, Int]

val index_map = sc.textFile("reference.txt").map {
  case line =>
    val key = (line.split("\t"))(1)
    val value = (line.split("\t"))(0).toInt
    mmap.addBinding(key, value)
}
```

Now how do I broadcast index_map?

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast the map using `sc.broadcast(mmap)`, but that simply distributes *a copy* of the map to your worker nodes, so that data is accessable on your worker nodes.

From your code, it looks like what you really want is to update the map from the workers, but you cannot do that. The workers do not have the same instance of the map, so they will each update their own map. What you can do instead is split the text file into key-value pairs (in parallel), then collect them and put them into the map:

```
val mmap = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String, collection.mutable.Set[Int]]() with collection.mutable.MultiMap[String, Int]

val index_map = sc.textFile("reference.txt")
  .collect
  .map (line => {
     val key = (line.split("\t"))(1)
     val value = (line.split("\t"))(0).toInt
     mmap.addBinding(key, value)
  })
```

To use Spark for a task where data will fit in a map seems somewhat overkill to me, though ;)

Comment: I do not want to edit the map from worker nodes. It is a read-only multimap that I want to use for lookup. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Okay... but you have an `addBinding` in your code which I believe inserts into the map? But if you only want to use the map for lookup, simply broadcast the map with `sc.broadcast(mmap)`.

Comment: Unfortunately,  it still acts like a hamp and not a multimap.  When I do a lookup   

val mmap = generateMultiMap()       

val values =  mmap.value.get("100")
      for (value <- values)
        println("Value is: " + value + "\n")

and then try to iterate through values, all I get is the last value for that key.

Comment: Okay, wait... I think I may see where you're going wrong. Everything that happens inside the `sc.textFile("reference.txt").map`-function is processed in parallel. This is why you cannot do an `addBinding` inside this function. You should either simply read the text file (using normal file utils) or if you insist on using `sc.textFile`, you should do `sc.textFile("reference.txt").collect()`. That will give you an array, you can then process with a map to fill your multimap. I have just updated my answer accordingly.